# slits and slots

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, cad

We are designing a part such that it is clamped. We are providing a slit for tube insertion. I need to know how much depth and width we can provide the slit sizing. Here I am attaching the slit image.

[image]

Comment: what goes into the slot? Cut to depth required.

Comment: You've omitted information on dimensions, material, forces, etc. The question is not answerable in its current form.

Comment: IT IS PROVIDED TO ACCOMDATE TUBE TO INNER DIA , DIAMENSIONS ARE WHAT WE NEEDED THE I.D OF TUBE IS 25MM AND I.D OF MOUNT IS 25MM AS WELL THICKNESS 2MM SLOT LENGTH WE GAVE IS 12 MM AND WIDTH IS 2MM MATERIAL IS PA12 , FORCE ACTING ON THE END IS IS 1.5kg THRUST, HOPE THIS INFO IS SUFFICENT, THANK YOU FOR REPLY AND ADVANCE AS WELL.

Comment: Add important info to the original question, leaving it in comments does not help. Also do not use ALL CAPS - it is taken as SHOUTING.